# Boost library on Solaris

Tags: c++, boost, solaris

We currently use RogueWave's SourcePro library tools.h++, DB modules. We are looking for open source alternative. Boost is first in sight.
But I am not seeing SunStudio compiler in Boost's regression test published on boost.org website. So do boost support Sun Studio ?

Also it seems that On Solaris and with Sun Studio's library is incompatible and needs to be linked with STLPort.

Now this is not possible in our case as our important third Party libraries are not compiled against STLport. So is there any other alternative? We are also open to other third party libraries other than boost but open source.

Comment: So what C++ Standard Library implementation _are_ your third-party libraries built against?

Comment: against Sun Studio stdLibc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost regression testers are all volunteers.

Apparently there is no one willing to run a boost test bot for Sun Studio; therefore boost "does not support" Sun Studio.

The best way to change that is to volunteer to run such a test bot; the directions for doing so are at http://www.boost.org/development/running_regression_tests.html

Once a test bot is in place and reporting results regularly (say, daily), then you should file bug reports against the libraries whose tests are failing.

We have had someone running Solaris tests in the past, but apparently they were not able to continue.